# Search&Replace XML nodes without modifying values and transform input file in HTML output

Tags: c#, xml, html, xslt

I read some answers here and tried to apply them to case...still struggling though.

My two objectives, resumed in the title:

1) I have to read big XML documents (up to 40 Megs), convert almost all the custom tags inside them, but leaving the content of those tags without any modification.

So, for example, my document is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Foo>
        <PARA>
            Text Value 1
        </PARA>
        <PARA>
            Text Value 2
        </PARA>
        <PARA>
            Text Value 3
        </PARA>
    </Foo>
    <SubNode>
        <SubExample>
            <PARA>
                Text Value 4
            </PARA>
            <PARA>
                Text Value 5
            </PARA>
            <PARA>
                Text Value 6
            </PARA>
        </SubExample>
    </SubNode>
</Root>
```

The resultant file has to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Foo>
        <p>
            Text Value 1
        </p>
        <p>
            Text Value 2
        </p>
        <p>
            Text Value 3`enter code here`
        </p>
    </Foo>
    <SubNode>
        <SubExample>
            <p>
                Text Value 4
            </p>
            <p>
                Text Value 5
            </p>
            <p>
                Text Value 6
            </p>
        </SubExample>
    </SubNode>
</Root>
```

My C# console application calls a XSLT file:

```
XslTransform myXslTransform;
        myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
        myXslTransform.Load(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\TransformXml2Html.xslt");
```

That is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/> 
  </xsl:param>-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PARA">
    <p></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But doing this way the content of `<p>` tags is empty...

2) Input XML file has to be transformed in a valid HTML5 valid document.

Thx in advance for your help

Comment: You forget to include <xsl:apply-templates/> under <p></p> element

Comment: Geez, was that easy :(
\me *noob*. Thx a lot mate!

What about the second point? Should I just change XSLT header in:

<xsl:output doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" method="html"/>

?

Comment: <xsl:output is enough to create your output as 'html' but to generate HTML output you must modify your XSLT to generate htm5 supported nodes